# Angular.js: Data-Binding input fields after http.get

Tags: angularjs

I have the following `app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
    angular
        .module('app')
        .config(['$urlRouterProvider','$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider,$stateProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

            $stateProvider
             .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                controller: 'homeCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    friends: ['$http', function($http) {
                         return $http.get('http://localhost:9000/ip').then(function(response) {
                            return response.data;
                        })
                    }]
                }
             })
```

I have the following controller `homeCtrl.js`:

```
angular
.module('app')
.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', 'friends', '$http', function($scope, friends, $http) {

    $scope.friends = friends;
    $scope.audit = function(auditDate, id){
        $http.get('http://westeros:9000/ip/' + id + '/' + auditDate).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            $scope.friends = data;
        });
    }
}]);
```

This is my template `home.html`:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
        <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in friend.aktuell">
            <input type="text" ng-model="friend.aktuell[key]">
        </span>
      <button ng-click="audit(auditDate, friend._id)" class="btn btn-info">Audit</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now if I select in my front end a date and click on "audit", the controller fetches data from my API which works great, however I would have expected that the view is automatically updated. How can I achieve that?

**Update:**

I think I identified the problem: I serve only one part of the friends model back `{...}`, but the view expects a multi-part array as friends like `[{..},{..}]`. Any idea how to only update that particular row `<li>` ? I mean is something like this even possible in the controller:

```
 $scope.friend.aktuell[key] = data;
```

Comment: Show your code in Fiddle

Comment: I updated all the code necessary above now.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, friends, $http) {

$scope.friends = friends;
$scope.audit = function(auditDate, id){
    $http.get('http://westeros:9000/ip/' + id + '/' + auditDate).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
     $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.friends = data;
        }
    }
});
```

for more info see this http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Comment: Aint working. Your linked doc says if I use ng-click, ng-apply is triggered automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a $scope.$apply() after your $scope.friends = data, this will force the data bindings to update.

Answer (score 0):

```
.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $http) { //<--here
    $scope.friends = [];
    $scope.audit = function(auditDate, id){
        $http.get('http://westeros:9000/ip/' + id + '/' + auditDate, {}).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            $scope.friends = data;
        }
    }
```